# c++ printing more pages with cairo in gtk+

Tags: printing, gtk, cairo

I would like to ask for help with printing more pages with gtk+.
I have conected few examples together, but I can print only one page.

I have some strings (numbers from zero to 50) in vector. After press button I would like to print this strings to several pages.
I pass this vector to callback function and there I want it print to several pages (according of size this vector).

I would like print several pages with same headings. At first page can be written zero to 30 and in second 31 to 50.

Please can some body help me improve my code (see bellow) to do this.
Thanks everybody.

```
GtkWidget *main_window = NULL;

static void draw_page (GtkPrintOperation *operation, GtkPrintContext *context, int page_nr, GtkWidget *data) {
    printf("DEBUG> draw_page\n");
    std::string* nadpisOdkaz = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "nadpisOdkaz"));
    std::vector <std::string>* vektorTextuOdkaz = reinterpret_cast<std::vector <std::string>*>(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "vektorTextuOdkaz"));

    std::string teloReportu;
    for (int i = 0; i < vektorTextuOdkaz->size(); i++) {
        teloReportu = teloReportu + vektorTextuOdkaz->at(i).c_str() + "\n";
    }

    PangoFontDescription *desc;
    cairo_t *cr = gtk_print_context_get_cairo_context (context);
    //drawing some image in head
    cairo_surface_t *surf1 = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("/path/to/some/image.png");
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surf1, 10, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);


    //some bigger text in head
    PangoLayout *nadpisLayout = gtk_print_context_create_pango_layout(context);
    pango_layout_set_text (nadpisLayout, nadpisOdkaz->c_str(), -1);
    desc = pango_font_description_from_string ("sans 28");
    pango_layout_set_font_description (nadpisLayout, desc);
    pango_font_description_free (desc);
    //setting position of printing text in head
    cairo_move_to (cr, 150, 30);
    pango_cairo_layout_path (cr, nadpisLayout);
    //filling with black
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_fill (cr);

    //printing rest of text
    PangoLayout* layout =  gtk_print_context_create_pango_layout(context);
    pango_layout_set_text (layout, teloReportu.c_str(), -1);
    desc = pango_font_description_from_string ("sans 18");
    pango_layout_set_font_description (layout, desc);
    pango_font_description_free (desc);
    cairo_move_to (cr, 20, 130);
    pango_cairo_layout_path (cr, layout);
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_fill (cr);

    //draw line under head
    cairo_move_to (cr, 10, 120);
    cairo_line_to (cr, 550, 120);
    cairo_stroke (cr);

    g_object_unref (nadpisLayout);
    g_object_unref (layout);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf1);
}

static GtkPrintSettings *settings = NULL;

static void do_print (GtkWidget* wid, GtkWidget* data) {
    printf("DEBUG> do_print\n");

  GtkPrintOperation *print;
  GtkPrintOperationResult res;

  print = gtk_print_operation_new ();

  if (settings != NULL)
    gtk_print_operation_set_print_settings (print, settings);

    gtk_print_operation_set_n_pages(print, 1);

  g_signal_connect (print, "draw_page", G_CALLBACK (draw_page), data);

  res = gtk_print_operation_run (print, GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_PRINT_DIALOG, GTK_WINDOW (main_window), NULL);

  if (res == GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_RESULT_APPLY)
    {
      if (settings != NULL)
        g_object_unref (settings);

      settings = GTK_PRINT_SETTINGS(g_object_ref (gtk_print_operation_get_print_settings (print)));
    }

  g_object_unref (print);
}


static GtkPageSetup *page_setup = NULL;

std::string Int2String (int cislo) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << cislo;
    return ss.str();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //some data to print
    std::string nadpis = "jmeno kategorie";
    std::vector<std::string> vektorTextu;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        vektorTextu.push_back(Int2String(i));
    }


  GtkWidget *button = NULL;
  GtkWidget *vbox = NULL;

  // Initialize GTK+
  g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, (GLogFunc) gtk_false, NULL);
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, g_log_default_handler, NULL);

  // Create the main window
  main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), 8);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (main_window), "Hello World");
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (main_window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_realize (main_window);
  g_signal_connect (main_window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

  // Create a vertical box with buttons
  vbox = gtk_vbox_new (TRUE, 6);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), vbox);

  button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_DIALOG_INFO);

  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT (main_window), "nadpisOdkaz", (gpointer)&nadpis);
  g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT (main_window), "vektorTextuOdkaz", (gpointer)&vektorTextu);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (do_print), (gpointer) main_window);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_CLOSE);
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  // Enter the main loop
  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you should look at [this solution from elementary](https://github.com/elementary/pantheon-print/blob/master/src/pantheon-print.vala). It works for multiple pages.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want to have two pages, then replace the 1 in gtk_print_operation_set_n_pages(print, 1) with 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now with help from Johnny and his link.
    The problem was that proc draw_page have readed still the same elements in a vector (if I have aplied advice which post Uli). 
    So I have adde some variables to remember when it finish.
    If somebody it helps here is solution:

```
int counter = 0;
int rowsPerPage = 30;

static void draw_page (GtkPrintOperation *operation, GtkPrintContext *context, int page_nr, GtkWidget *data) {
    printf("DEBUG> draw_page\n");
    std::string* nadpisOdkaz = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "nadpisOdkaz"));
    std::vector <std::string>* vektorTextuOdkaz = reinterpret_cast<std::vector <std::string>*>(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "vektorTextuOdkaz"));

    std::string teloReportu;
    for (int i = counter * rowsPerPage; i < counter * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage; i++) {
        teloReportu = teloReportu + vektorTextuOdkaz->at(i).c_str() + "\n";
    }
    ++counter;
    .
    .
    .
```

and in proc do_print it only need to know how many pages wil be printed:

```
std::vector <std::string>* vektorTextuOdkaz = reinterpret_cast<std::vector <std::string>*>(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(data), "vektorTextuOdkaz"));
    gtk_print_operation_set_n_pages(print, vektorTextuOdkaz->size()/rowsPerPage);
```

Thanks for help.